# Position elements in a top->down left->right manner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main container `<div>` which holds 4 or 5 other sub `<div>`s. The container has a fixed height and a fixed width. What is the best way to position the sub divs so that they are arranged in a top->down then left->right manner?

I've tried floating the sub divs but that just gives me a left->right then top->down order.

Basically I want this

```
[ sub div 1][sub div 3][sub div 4]
[ sub div 2][         ][sub div 5]
```

When I mark up the code like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="subdiv">sub div 1...</div>
    <div class="subdiv">sub div 2...</div>
    <div class="subdiv">sub div 3...</div>
    <div class="subdiv">sub div 4...</div>
    <div class="subdiv">sub div 5...</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the sub divs can have variable heights but fixed widths.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have to support IE6? (It may matter, there are a lot of CSS tricks that don't work on IE6, and while we all may want to ignore IE6, in some sectors -- particularly large corporate sectors -- it remains a significant browser. Outside of those, much less so. Hence the question.)

Comment: For this we just need IE 7 (strict dtd) and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no way to do it.

There is some CSS3 that works only on some browsers to support multi-column layout (-moz-column-width, etc...) but I don't know whether it would work with DIVs in the content. And I'm fairly certain it it's not supported in IE7

The way I'd do it would be to break up the content into 3 columns containers

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='column'>
        <div class="subdiv">sub div 1...</div>
        <div class="subdiv">sub div 2...</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class="subdiv">sub div 3...</div>
        <div class="subdiv">sub div 4...</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class="subdiv">sub div 5...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of having to break it up for the sole reason that the list of sub div's is dynamic, and their varying height makes it hard to calculate exactly where I should break them up. I'll try to think of something on that route.

Comment: You might want to search for a jquery plugin or something of the sort to handle your content layout on the client side once the page is rendered (something like this maybe? http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/). I've had to use this approach a few times to solve similar issues

Comment: @Damp would love to look at that link but it's blocked from work :(.

Comment: @ferrari fan do you have access to github? https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your help, I took the approach of splitting the columns based on the examples of the columnizer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS on the DIVs:

```
display: inline-block
```

Comment: That's going to do the same thing (ordering-wise) as `float: left;`

Comment: yeah this does not work the way I need it to. I've modified the question to show the kind of markup that I'm using.

Comment: There's this tempting "delete" link... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this natively is to use CSS3 columns (as Damp mentioned) but there are some articles on how to achieve a similar effect with JavaScript as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173934/html-newspaper-columns). That case is actually more complicated than yours.

I'm thinking the best way to do it with JS would be to first split it evenly into column containers as Damp suggested with a best guess. This should help for those with JS disabled. Then us JS to measure heights of the subdivs and move them if the initial guess was off. Assuming you're using a server side language to generate the page, you should be able to split the columns evenly. You can probably even make a good estimation on the split by checking the length of content (assuming its text) as a heuristic for the likely height of the subdiv.